# Print feature names for SelectKBest where k value is inside param_grid of GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I tried parameter combinations of k from SelectKBest and n_components of PCA inside the param_grid. I'm able to print the **k value** and **n_components** using the code below. I'm posting the entire code, so you understand from which list the features are being taken from

```
#THE FIRST FEATURE HAS TO BE THE LABEL

featurelist = ['poi', 'exercised_stock_options', 'expenses', 'from_messages', 
           'from_poi_to_this_person', 'from_this_person_to_poi', 'other', 
           'restricted_stock', 'salary', 'shared_receipt_with_poi', 
           'to_messages', 'total_payments', 'total_stock_value', 
           'ratio_from_poi', 'ratio_to_poi']

enronml = pd.DataFrame(enron[['poi', 'exercised_stock_options', 'expenses', 'from_messages', 
           'from_poi_to_this_person', 'from_this_person_to_poi', 'other', 
           'restricted_stock', 'salary', 'shared_receipt_with_poi', 
           'to_messages', 'total_payments', 'total_stock_value', 
           'ratio_from_poi', 'ratio_to_poi']].copy())


enronml = enronml.to_dict(orient="index")
dataset = enronml

#featureFormat, takes the dictionary as the dataset, converts the first 
feature in featurelist into label

data = featureFormat(dataset, featurelist, sort_keys = True)
labels, features = targetFeatureSplit(data)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, 
test_size=0.20, random_state=0)


pca = PCA()
gnba = GaussianNB()
steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
     ('best', SelectKBest()),
     ('pca', pca),
     ('gnba', gnba)]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

parameters = [    
{
'best__k':[3],
'pca__n_components': [1,2]
},
{
'best__k':[4],
'pca__n_components': [1,2,3]
},
{
'best__k':[5],
'pca__n_components': [1,2,3,4]
},
]

cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
gnbawithpca = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameters, cv=cv, 
scoring="f1")
gnbawithpca.fit(X_train,y_train)

means = gnbawithpca.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = gnbawithpca.cv_results_['std_test_score']


for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, 
gnbawithpca.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
          % (mean, std * 2, params))
```

I'm able to get a result like this

```
0.480 (+/-0.510) for {'best__k': 3, 'pca__n_components': 1}
0.534 (+/-0.409) for {'best__k': 3, 'pca__n_components': 2}
0.480 (+/-0.510) for {'best__k': 4, 'pca__n_components': 1}
0.534 (+/-0.409) for {'best__k': 4, 'pca__n_components': 2}
0.565 (+/-0.342) for {'best__k': 4, 'pca__n_components': 3}
0.480 (+/-0.510) for {'best__k': 5, 'pca__n_components': 1}
0.513 (+/-0.404) for {'best__k': 5, 'pca__n_components': 2}
0.473 (+/-0.382) for {'best__k': 5, 'pca__n_components': 3}
0.448 (+/-0.353) for {'best__k': 5, 'pca__n_components': 4}
```

**I want to know what features were selected, for example, when best_k = 5, I want to know the names of those 5 features.**

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? You have simply stated what you are doing, not what the problem is.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot the last line.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED

When you define the pipeline, to be used in GridSearchCV, you name each step:

```
steps = [('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
     ('best', SelectKBest()),
     ('pca', pca),
     ('gnba', gnba)]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
```

you do that for two reasons:

So you can define the parameters in the parameter grid (the names are required to identify which step you are defining the parameters for).

So you can access the attributes of the step from the GridSearchCV object (this answers your question).

```
skb_step = gnbawithpca.best_estimator_.named_steps['best']

# Get SelectKBest scores, rounded to 2 decimal places, name them "feature_scores"

feature_scores = ['%.2f' % elem for elem in skb_step.scores_ ]

# Get SelectKBest pvalues, rounded to 3 decimal places, name them "feature_scores_pvalues"

feature_scores_pvalues = ['%.3f' % elem for elem in  skb_step.pvalues_ 
]

# Get SelectKBest feature names, whose indices are stored in 'skb_step.get_support',

# create a tuple of feature names, scores and pvalues, name it "features_selected_tuple"

features_selected_tuple=[(featurelist[i+1], feature_scores[i], 
feature_scores_pvalues[i]) for i in skb_step.get_support(indices=True)]

# Sort the tuple by score, in reverse order

features_selected_tuple = sorted(features_selected_tuple, key=lambda 
feature: float(feature[1]) , reverse=True)

# Print

print ' '
print 'Selected Features, Scores, P-Values'
print features_selected_tuple
```

Comment: How do I get the feature names? I can see comment above...# Get SelectKBest feature names, whose indices are stored in 'skb_step.get_support'